# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run JUnit tests from ANT

Tags: testing, ant, junit

I'm having problems with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run my JUnit tests from ANT using the runtestsreport task in thefollowing build.xml; I know the other tasks work, it's just the actual running of the tests that's the problem.

I've tried lots of adjustments based on questions posted on here but I can't fix it; what I really need is a dev to pair with but they've all gone home for the day.

Can anyone help?

The build.xml file is

```
<property name="build" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\build"/>
<property name="testsbuild" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\build\esstestapp\tests"/>
<property name="frameworkbuild" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\build\esstestapp\framework"/>
<property name="rawtestreports" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\reports\raw"/>
<property name="htmltestreports" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\reports\html"/>
<property name="reports" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\reports"/>
<property name="src" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\src"/>
<property name="testsrc" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\src\esstestapp\tests"/>
<property name="seleniumtools" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\junit-4.8.2"/>
<property name="junittools" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2"/>

<target name="init">   
    <tstamp/>   
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rawtestreports}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${htmltestreports}"/>
</target> 

<path id="tools.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${seleniumtools}" includes="**/*.jar"/>   
    <fileset dir="${junittools}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path> 

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source" >    
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="tools.classpath" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="frameworkjar" depends="compile">        
    <jar destfile="${frameworkbuild}/jar/framework.jar" basedir="${frameworkbuild}" />        
</target>

<target name="testsjar" depends="compile">        
    <jar destfile="${testsbuild}/jar/tests.jar" basedir="${testsbuild}" />
</target>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${seleniumtools}" includes="**/*.jar"/>   
    <fileset dir="${junittools}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${testsbuild}/jar" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${frameworkbuild}/jar" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path> 

<target name="runtests" depends="compile, frameworkjar, testsjar" description="runs the tests" >    
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes" fork="no"> 
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />                 

        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${rawtestreports}"> 
            <formatter type="xml"/> 
                <fileset dir="${testsrc}">
                    <include name="**/*.java"/> 
                </fileset> 
        </batchtest> 
    </junit>    
</target>

<target name="runtestsreport" depends="runtests">
    <junitreport todir="${reports}">
        <fileset dir="${rawtestreports}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" /> 
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${htmltestreports}" /> 
    </junitreport>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Clean up">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>    
    <delete dir="${reports}"/>
</target>
```

I get this error (and this type of error for each test class)

```
Credentials (wrong name: esstestapp/tests/Credentials)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Credentials (wrong name: esstestapp/tests/Credentials)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)...
```

I've ran ant in -verbose mode to check the classpath out but I can't see the problem (even though I know that it's staring me in the face)

```
[junit] Implicitly adding C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant-launcher
.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1
.8.2\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant-junit4.jar to C
LASSPATH
[junit] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\java.exe' with
arguments:
[junit] '-classpath'
[junit] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\java.exe' with
arguments:
[junit] '-classpath'
[junit] 'C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\junit-4.8.2\junit.jar;C:\User
s\waltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\junit-4.8.2\junitsrc.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\worksp
ace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\
ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\bsh-1.3.0.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\se
lenium-2.0rc2\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\seleni
um-2.0rc2\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2
.0rc2\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\seleni
um-2.0rc2\commons-io-2.0.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.
0rc2\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\
cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\guava-
r09.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\hamcrest-all-1.1.j
ar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\htmlunit-2.8.jar;C:\Use
rs\waltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar;C:\User
s\waltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\httpclient-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\wal
tersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\w
orkspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\httpmime-4.0.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspac
e\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\jcommander-1.13.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\
tools\selenium-2.0rc2\jna.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0
rc2\json-20080701.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\juni
t-dep-4.8.1.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\nekohtml-1
.9.14.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\sac-1.3.jar;C:\U
sers\waltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\selenium-java-2.0rc2-srcs.jar;
C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\selenium-java-2.0rc2.jar;C
:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Use
rs\waltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\testng-6.0.1-nobsh-noguice.jar;C
:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\wa
ltersj\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\walters
j\workspace\ESS\tools\selenium-2.0rc2\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\work
space\ESS\build\esstestapp\tests\jar\tests.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\b
uild\esstestapp\framework\jar\framework.jar;C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS;C:\P
rogram Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\
ant-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files\
apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant-jun
it4.jar'
```

Any eyes over this to help me get the tests running would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

James

**Update**

I observe that if I edit tests.classpath to remove the following 2 lines then the error I see switches to a ClassNotFound which makes sense as it has no references to the .jar files that contain the classes.

```
<fileset dir="${testsbuild}/jar" includes="**/*.jar"/>
<fileset dir="${frameworkbuild}/jar" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

With the above 2 lines present in the tests.classpath is happily finds them but with the wrong name and it's that error I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem caused by the following **jar** command:

```
<jar destfile="${testsbuild}/jar/tests.jar" basedir="${testsbuild}" />
```

The *testsbuild* property should be set to

```
<property name="testsbuild" location="C:\<path on my machine>\workspace\ESS\build"/>
```

### Explanation

The file *Credentials.class* was compiled as the class *esstestapp.tests.Credentials*. It needs to be found on the classpath as the file:

esstestapp/tests/Credentials.class

Comment: After making the modification you suggested to the testsbuild property I now see java.lang.ClassNotFoundException errors for each class that contains tests :(

Comment: Sounds like fixing one problem has caused another. Are you still getting the "wrong name" explanation within the exception? That was what my suggested fix was trying to solve. Sorry looks like we need more details to solve your second issue.

Comment: When I made the changes suggested in your answer I was only seeing ClassNotFoundException. I'll update the original question to explain in more detail the project though any pointers to what more detail I could provide would be good :)